# How to add a custom UI/intellisense inside Monaco editor?

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I want to add a custom pill element next to the import definitions in my Monaco Editor just like in the image below. So is there a way to extend Monaco editor's UI or is there any API that'll let me do so? I couldn't find any information on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `Monaco.IStandaloneCodeEditor.deltaDecorations` which allows to add any type of HTML in the editor. Text content will be moved to avoid overlapping of decorations and text.